# R shiny: sliderinout prior to selectinput

Tags: r, shiny

Using Shiny, I want to be able to filter on one variable (year) prior to making a barplot based on a certain time unit (year, quarter, month) In other words, I want to use a `sliderinput` followed by a `selectinput`. I can get the UI to work but I don't know which syntax to use for the server part.

So basically, I'm looking for a filter option for the server part of `sliderInput('year_s', 'select year', 2015, 2018, c(2015,2018))`

I hope someone can help me out with this.

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(ID=c(1:200),
                  year=rep(c(2015,2016,2017,2018),50),
                  quarter=rep(c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2),20),
                  month=rep(c('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08'),10)
                  )

dat$year <- as.factor(dat$year)
dat$quarter <- as.factor(paste(dat$year, '_', dat$quarter))
dat$month <- as.factor(paste(dat$year, '_', dat$month))



ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Header title"),

  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput('year_s', 'select year', 2015, 2018, c(2015,2018)),

    selectInput(inputId = 'Timeunit',
                label='Time unit',
                choices=c('year','quarter','month'),
                selected='year')
  ),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
))





server <- function(input, output) {
  selectInput= reactive({
    dataset <- dat %>% group_by_(input$Timeunit) %>% summarise(number = n())

  })

  output$plot <-renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=selectInput(), aes_string(x=input$Timeunit,y="number"))  + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
      labs(title="Plot title" , y ="Total") +
      theme_classic() + 
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
  })

}
shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(ID=c(1:200),
                  year=rep(c(2015,2016,2017,2018),50),
                  quarter=rep(c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2),20),
                  month=rep(c('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08'),10)
)

dat$year <- as.factor(dat$year)
dat$quarter <- as.factor(paste(dat$year, '_', dat$quarter))
dat$month <- as.factor(paste(dat$year, '_', dat$month))
years <- unique(dat$year)



ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Header title"),

  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput('year_s', 'select year', 2015, 2018, c(2015,2018)),
    selectInput('Timeunit','Time unit',choices=c('year','quarter','month'),selected='year')
  ),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
))

server <- function(input, output) {

  d1 <- eventReactive(input$year_s,{
    subset(dat, year %in% input$year_s[1]:input$year_s[2])
  })

  selectInput <- reactive({
    d1() %>% group_by_(input$Timeunit) %>% summarise(number = n())
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=selectInput(), aes_string(x=input$Timeunit,y="number"))  + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
      labs(title="Plot title" , y ="Total") +
      theme_classic() + 
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
  })

}

shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. When I use your code I get the following error: Error in force(default) : argument "value" is missing, with no default. Any idea where that's coming from?

Comment: try above please

Comment: Made a small change to have the slider use the correct numnbers automatically: sliderInput('year_s', 'select year', min(years), max(years), value = years)

Comment: Do you also know how to combine filters? E.g. if I add a radiobutton using radioButtons('option1', 'option2',choices = c('option1','option2'),selected = 'option1'). What should I change to object d1 in the server part to make this work?